# I can't read unlocked tables within the session in MySQL adodb connection

Tags: mysql, vb.net, adodb

The following SQL statement in my ADODB connection (VB.NET 2.0)
cnData is my connection object.

```
cnData.Execute("lock tables t_itemprocess_rawmaterial write")

cnData.BeginTrans()

cnData.Execute("insert into t_itemprocess_rawmaterial(processitem_id,rm_id) values(10,34)")

Dim lrsData As New ADODB.Recordset

lrsData.Open("select * from t_item where item_id=651", cnData, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic)
  // above code gets error like table t_item was not locked...

cnData.CommitTrans()
cnData.Execute("unlock tables")
```

Give me suggestion what is wrong this code and how to read unlocked tables within the session.

Comment: As the duplicate says, you need to lock _all_ the tables you are going to use.